# psql: FATAL: could not open file "base/11951/11717": Read-only file system

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to access the postgreSQL database from CLI. When I login as postgres and enter command

I'm getting error

```
psql: FATAL:  could not open file "base/11951/11717": Read-only file system
```

I'm new to this. Any pointers on where to look at would be a great help. TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like the VM where the database was hosted went to Read-only mode for an unknown issue.

```
$ fsck
```

command helped to repair linux filesystems and was able to access psql db.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your system has detected disk errors and put the filesystem in read-only mode to protect its self from possible corruption.

Check `dmesg` and the kernel log files.

I strongly advise you to read and act on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes It indicates that the server had a general error...(Happened to me yesterday, the moment the server was restarted, the "FATAL:  could not open file" disappeared.