# FATAL: could not open file "base/13128/1259": Read-only file system

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, psql, pgadmin-4

I have an error when try connecting to postgresql (when entering the password in pgadmin 4)

The error is FATAL: could not open file "base/13128/1259": Read-only file system

I've searched about the error in google and got this

[psql: FATAL: could not open file "base/11951/11717": Read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249841/psql-fatal-could-not-open-file-base-11951-11717-read-only-file-system)

I've tried fsck in command prompt but still doesn't works.

Someone here can help me with this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something wrong with mounted device where PostgreSQL keep its data. Ask sysops/sysadmins if any.

Comment: This is not a PostgreSQL problem, but an operating system problem. Your database is running on a read-only filesystem, and the reason is unknown. Check the syslog.